# How to copy non-text site columns between sites using REST/JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api, http-400-bad-request

I am attempting to set up a  SharePoint 2013 workflow which will copy the contents of a list item from a subsite to a logging list on its parent site. I have successfully set up the HTTP web service call and all the single and multi-line text fields in the list copy as intended. The list also has a number of choice fields and user fields but as soon as I add any of these the workflow fails and returns a BadRequest in the log.

how can I get the workflow to pass the contents of my choice and username fields as well? I'm pretty sure the problem is with my Type and Values I'm putting into my parameters dictionary build but I am new to REST/JSON and I don't know what the fix is.

Comment: Workflow 2010 or 2013? Can you please add any screenshot or something of how your adding data to logging list?

Comment: 2013 Workflow. HTTP Calls aren't available in 2010.